# Scheduling Email for 3AM and Gneivas Daas

Tags: halacha, technology, time, sheker-false

Is is permitted to schedule an email for the wee hours of the night, like 3AM, to give the impression that you were working late?

Is it significantly well known that there are services like Boomerang and Outlook that support delayed emails so that whoever is mislead should know better, or, is this tantamount to engaging in misleading practice and is forbidden due to Geneivas Daas?

Comment: More like sending it at 645am _instead_ of 3am so people think you go to sleep and wake up at normal adult times.

Comment: Are you billing based on this? Or is it just to boast? The fact that it is known may play a difference also.

Comment: I get loads of email with a time stamp of early in the AM. Granted, most of these emails is from a machine, anyway, like Costco. Email timestamps pose many problems that obscure reality. Often, I've sent my office email address something at 10 P.M. and when I arrive at the office, the timestamp is 4 AM. Maybe the yahoo server delayed picking it up, maybe my office server delayed receiving it. Who knows why the stamp is different? Point is, I think considering so many glitches, why would an average recipient care that much either way to be fooled by it?

Comment: @GershonGold as stated in the question, this is to give your correspondent who may be a boss or colleague the impression that you're working long hours and  hard working and take your job very seriously. That might, together with other favorable job reviews,  translate into promotions and bonuses...but the immediate question is one of  גנבת דעת.

Comment: @Yoni I don't know the halachos of gneivas da'as so well - is there really a _hetter_ of "you should have known better" for me to to do something with the intent of misleading?

Comment: @Yez from what I understand, if the person being cheated is cheating himself it is permitted (so action by the cheater done spesificly to cheat), but doing an action spesificly (only) to mislead is forbidden

Answer (score 2):

The intent being to mislead, i should think it assur.

Comment: Well as interesting as this is, we have no idea who you are that we should value your opinions at all. Please [edit] in a source for your claims if you want your answer to be valuable to the community.

Comment: Shoel, this is not a proper answer for MY for the reasons stated above. See [this post](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/a-beginner-s-guide-to-my-how-is-this-site-different-from-other-judaism-sites) to help you understand how MY is different from other sites you might be used to, esp. point 4

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.rabbimanning.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/Geneivat-Daat.pdf

And [sulchal aruch harav 12](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh6/4/1/12.htm)-26

I understand that it is forbidden to do an action with the intention to deceive

But if the action you do is not with the intention to deceive and the person devices himself it is permitted (you do not need to worry what someone else is thinking) unless there is a hazaka and your acction is not like the hazoko

**So if it is a positive thing to give the impression that you were working late then it seems to be forbidden**